# How to do a line break and horizontal space for blocks with 'nicematrix'?

Tags: block, nicematrix

I don't know what to do anymore, I try to generate a table with labels by using the \block command (I am using XeLateX, if that is important, because with the default one I get a pixelated font).
My Questions are:

- How do I make a line break when using the \block command?
- How can I add horizontal space between the left label and the table and vertical space between the top label and the table?
- Why is there one vertical line, which is much longer than the other ones?

Here is what I got:
[image: What I got.]

And here is what I want:
[image]

Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}[code-before = \cellcolor[HTML]{FCAA78}{3-3,3-4,3-5,3- 
6,4-7,4-8,4-9,5-6,5-7} \cellcolor[HTML]{F8696B}{3-7,3-8,3-9,5-8} \cellcolor[HTML]{FFEB84}{3-10,3- 
11,3-13,3-14,4-4,4-5,4-6,4-10,4-11,4-13,5-9} \cellcolor[HTML]{CBDC81}{3-12,5-10} \cellcolor[HTML] 
{97CD7E}{4-12,5-11} \cellcolor[HTML]{63BE7B}{4-14,5-12,5-13,5-14}] 
\Block{1-13}{Loading Volume [$\mu$L]}\\
\Block{4-1}{\rotate Injection Volume [$\mu$L]} & & 5   & 5.3  & 10   & 10.3 & 15   & 20   & 25   & 30   
& 35   & 40   & 45   & 50   \\ \cline{2-14} 
& 1  & 0.2 & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.15 & 0.15 & 0.1  & 0.15 & 0.15 \\ \cline{2- 
14}
& 5  & & 0.15 & 0.15 & 0.15 & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.15 & 0.15 & 0.05 & 0.15 & 0    \\ \cline{2- 
14}
& 10 & & & & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.15 & 0.1  & 0.05 & 0  & 0  & 0  
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use the keys `first-row` and `first-col` for the legends. By doing that, you can use `\hline` (instead of `cline`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{c*{12}{|c}}[first-col,first-row]
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FCAA78}{2-2,2-3,2-4,2-5,3-6,3-7,3-8,4-5,4-6}
  \cellcolor[HTML]{F8696B}{2-6,2-7,2-8,4-7} 
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFEB84}{2-9,2-10,2-12,2-13,3-3,3-4,3-5,3-9,3-10,3-12,4-8} 
  \cellcolor[HTML]{CBDC81}{2-11,4-9} 
  \cellcolor[HTML]{97CD7E}{3-11,4-10} 
  \cellcolor[HTML]{63BE7B}{3-13,4-11,4-12,4-13}
\Body 
\Block{1-14}{Loading Volume [$\mu$L]}\\[1mm]
\Block{4-1}<\rotate>{Injection\\ Volume [$\mu$L]} & & 5   & 5.3  & 10   & 10.3 & 15   & 20   & 25   & 30   
& 35   & 40   & 45   & 50   \\ \hline
& 1  & 0.2 & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.15 & 0.15 & 0.1  & 0.15 & 0.15 \\ \hline
& 5  & & 0.15 & 0.15 & 0.15 & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.15 & 0.15 & 0.05 & 0.15 & 0    \\ \hline
& 10 & & & & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.15 & 0.1  & 0.05 & 0  & 0  & 0  
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [white] (5-|1) -- (5-|14) ;
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The instruction

```
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw [white] (5-|1) -- (5-|14) ;
```

is only in order to have a perfect result for the vertical rules. Without that white line, they are a bit too long (because these vertical rules were in fact designed to fit nicely with a last horizontal rule).

---

In your case, it's also possible to compute automatically the color of the cells from their content (with the same output):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{collcell}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcolumntype { C } { > { \collectcell \MyColorCell } c < { \endcollectcell } } 

\NewDocumentCommand \MyColorCell { m } 
  {
    \OnlyMainNiceMatrix
      {
        \str_case:nn { #1 } 
          { 
            { 0 }    { \cellcolor[HTML]{63BE7B} }
            { 0.05 } { \cellcolor[HTML]{97CD7E} }
            { 0.1 }  { \cellcolor[HTML]{CBDC81} }
            { 0.15 } { \cellcolor[HTML]{FFEB84} }
            { 0.2 }  { \cellcolor[HTML]{FCAA78} }
            { 0.25 } { \cellcolor[HTML]{F8696B} }
          }
      }
    #1
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{C*{12}{|C}}[colortbl-like,first-col,first-row] 
\Block{1-14}{Loading Volume [$\mu$L]}\\[1mm]
\Block{4-1}<\rotate>{Injection\\ Volume [$\mu$L]}
&    & 5   & 5.3  & 10   & 10.3 & 15   & 20   & 25   & 30   & 35   & 40   & 45   & 50   \\ \hline
& 1  & 0.2 & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.15 & 0.15 & 0.1  & 0.15 & 0.15 \\ \hline
& 5  &     & 0.15 & 0.15 & 0.15 & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.15 & 0.15 & 0.05 & 0.15 & 0    \\ \hline
& 10 &     &      &      & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.15 & 0.1  & 0.05 & 0    & 0    & 0    
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you for you help, this is exactly how I wanted it!